# Почему нет раздела Legacy в UI в Unity как на скриншоте?

Tags: unity3d, ui, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui

[image]

При выборе UI должна появляться вот такая вкладка Legacy, как на этом скриншоте, но у меня ее нет. После Event System ничего нет. Погуглил как ее получить, но не нашел. Как сделать так, чтобы она появилась?

Comment: ¿А это случаем не совсем древние компоненты? Их кажется лет 6 назад выпилили окончательно.

Comment: в версии 2021.3.18f1 они есть, у меня версия 2020.3.30f1

Answer (score 0):

Возможно просто пакет не установлен. Добавь его через Window->Package Manager.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]